# Where is the rawValue property?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a very simple app that restricted which direction you can rotate the iPhone. In the ViewController I override the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` as follow:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: (UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue ))

}
```

And when I look at the implementation of UIInterfaceOrientationMask:

```
public struct UIInterfaceOrientationMask : OptionSetType {
    public init(rawValue: UInt)

    public static var Portrait: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var LandscapeLeft: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var LandscapeRight: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var PortraitUpsideDown: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var Landscape: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var All: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
    public static var AllButUpsideDown: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }
}
```

I can't find the property `rawValue` on for example `Portrait` property. Where `rawValue` comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Just return this:

```
return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft]
```

There's no point in getting the raw value just to convert it back to it's original value! :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you need to return something of type `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` rather than `[UIInterfaceOrientationMask]`?

Comment: You are returning something of type UIInterfaceOrientationMask.  The magic is handled by the OptionSetType which is ArrayLiteralConvertible.  In converting an array literal, it treats the members like a set and combines them into the proper value of the proper type.  Google OptionSetType and read a few of the tutorials available on the net.